# Xubuntu is going to sleep mode when I screen lock

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

Xubuntu 18.04.2
When I lock screen, lock screen not appears it directly goes to dark screen/sleep, it doesn't wake up after I press any key or Esc.

When the computer is idle for a while and it gone to screen lock, I don't know it goes to sleep mode or what!

This situation if I toggle Caps Lock button, caps lock indicator light is on/off. but display is still dark. If I press power button it directly goes to shut down (no display but I can understand it is going to shut down if I click Esc some msg are shown...) 
Then I power it again and work.

btw, I am doing `Ctrl+Alt+F1` then `Ctrl+Alt+F7` right now, but this is irritating, need a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just type the password even on sleep.